# Having what week day is on left column

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I have the following http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/314bf7ab3 but where i have the day of the calendar, i also want to put if it's monday, tuesday or so on...

In the documentation at https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html#daysmodedetails they should have the day but i never manage to output the value.

Can someone give me a hand?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue is in the scale label template definition.

TLDR: Once you rename the template like the following, it should work:

```
var dateToStr = scheduler.date.date_to_str("%j %F, %l");
scheduler.templates["timeline_scale_label"] = function(section_id, section_label, section_options){
  return dateToStr(section_label);
};
```

Right now you have it declared like this:

```
var dateToStr = scheduler.date.date_to_str("%j %F, %l");
scheduler.templates["weektimeline_scale_label"] = function(section_id, section_label, section_options){
   return dateToStr(section_label);
};
```

Where the name of the template is **weektimeline_scale_label**. But the timeline view is declared under the **timeline** name:

```
scheduler.createTimelineView({
...
    name:"timeline", 
...
});
```

The template must contain the name of the timeline view (since the scheduler allows creating multiple timelines), i.e. **scheduler.templates[`${timeline.name}_scale_label`].

So in your case, the template should be named **timeline_scale_label**:

```
var dateToStr = scheduler.date.date_to_str("%j %F, %l");
scheduler.templates["timeline_scale_label"] = function(section_id, section_label, section_options){
  return dateToStr(section_label);
};
```

or

```
var dateToStr = scheduler.date.date_to_str("%j %F, %l");
scheduler.templates.timeline_scale_label = function(section_id, section_label, section_options){
  return dateToStr(section_label);
};
```

Snippet: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/7ef709780

Also note, that the Day Timeline view doesn't support markers (scheduler.addMarkedTimespan), but you can color cells using `scheduler.templates.timeline_cell_class` template:

```
scheduler.templates.timeline_cell_class = function(evs, date, section){
    const cellDateValue = section.key;// day-timeline cells receive date values in section.key
    if(cellDateValue >= new Date(2019,11,20) && cellDateValue < new Date(2019,11,21)){
        return "blue_section";
    }
    return "";
};
```

Here is a demo: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/sxorcz6s